# Python csv group rows by n row numbers

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with several thousand rows that I am trying to parse. I want to group the rows into sets of 5 then calculate the average of the 'Value' column as well as return the min and max 'Value' of that group and the End Time of when that min and max value occurred.

```
Start Time,End Time,Value
12-4-2014 9:00,12-4-2014 10:00,3221.3
12-4-2014 10:00,12-4-2014 11:00,3233.5
12-4-2014 11:00,12-4-2014 12:00,3543.6
12-4-2014 12:00,12-4-2014 13:00,3711.5
12-4-2014 13:00,12-4-2014 14:00,3732.4
etc....
```

I am thinking I have to create a dictionary for each set of 5 then run some stats on that dictionary?

Comment: Your grouping is fixed, i.e. chunks of 5 rows only, or is it by date or some other criteria?

Comment: Grouping is fixed by chunks of 5 rows only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `csv.reader` is merely an iterator over the rows that returns each row as a list

you can convert any iterator into a *sequence* with `list(iterator)`

you can group any **sequence** as follows

```
step = 5
split_data = [data[i:i+step] for i in range(0,len(data),step)]
```

you can then iterate over each group

```
split_data = (data[i:i+step] for i in range(0,len(data),step))
#note i use an iterator comprehension this time since i dont want to loop over the stuff twice

for grouping in split_data:
    analyze(grouping)
```

Comment: Or, use the `grouper` recipe, or even something like: `for group in iter(lambda: list(islice(fileobj, 5)), []):`...

Comment: I agree ... but to be honest `izip_longest(*[my_iter]*group_size)` is a little cryptic